# Changes on imported JS files with Vue CLI project trigger page reload

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3, webpack-hmr

When I make changes to any function .js file under ./src/fn hot reload is not working and triggers a page reload.

I have been trying to make configure vue.config.js to include the directory to HMR correctly. Also I tried using my custom helpers as a Vue.use(myPlugin).

```
/* functions.js (just a part of it) */
export const Functions = {
  game: {
    helper: helpers,
    turn: turn,
    ui: ui,
    validate: validate,
    card: cards
  },
}

/* main.js */
import Functions from './functions.js';
Vue.prototype.$myFn = Functions;
```

Expected HMR to work but instead get a full page reload when making changes to functions.js (or any underlying js file imported in functions.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your own objects and functions to the Vue prototype is a bit of an anti-pattern. In this case, Webpack can't determine the extent of the changes made so it falls back to a page reload. This is because ES modules can be statically analysed whereas global objects cannot be.

Here's some articles about static analysis:

- [Static Program Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis)
- [ES Modules in Depth](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-modules-in-depth)

Remove the functions from the Vue protoype and always use [ES modules](https://flaviocopes.com/es-modules/) to structure your functions. Then you can `import` them into other modules or components without using the legacy style global hack approach of yesteryear.